# Redirect domain to a specific page on another domain

Tags: .htaccess, perch

I have a website www.mainwebsite.com with a page located at www.mainpage.com/pagename

I need to redirect a new domian name to this page. so www.newdomainname.com should redirect to www.mainpage.com/pagename

How can I do this with the htaccess?

My site is using Perch Runway too not sure if this will change anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using the following rules in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newdomainname\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newdomainname\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mainpage.com/pagename/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

So if either of `newdomainname.com` or `www.newdomainname.com` it will then using a 301 redirect take you to `www.mainpage.com/pagename`.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** you test this.